# MySQL Updating syntax

Tags: mysql, vb.net

using mysql update

```
Dim OfficerCreated, OfficerID As String
Dim OfficerTodaysDateandTime As Date
OfficerTodaysDateandTime = Now
OfficerID = lvOfficerGrid.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(0).Text
OfficerCreated = lvOfficerGrid.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(5).Text
UpdateOfficer = "UPDATE pcms.users SET user_fname = '" & Me.txtOfficerFname.Text.ToUpper & "', user_mname = '" & Me.txtOfficerMname.Text.ToUpper & "'," & _
"user_lname = '" & Me.txtOfficerLname.Text.ToString & "',user_status = '" & Me.AccountStatus.ToString & "',user_created = '" & OfficerCreated & "',user_updated = '" & OfficerTodaysDateandTime & "' WHERE user_id = " & _
"'" & OfficerID & "'"
```

OfficerID is an Integer value which is loaded in listview column1

OfficerCreated is a DATETIME which is loaded in listview column5

OfficerTodaysDateandTime is a DATETIME

im getting error in updating..
whats wrong in my codes?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Change to [parameterized SQL queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlparameter.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 
WHERE [where you want to make changes]
```

to update various column fields use comma-separated, not an ampersand.

And it is also recommended to put a where clause, or every row will be affected with the update.

Comment: `&` is string concatenation operator in `VB`. Not an error.